# Polling Interval for JMS MessageListener with SQS Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs

I am using amazon sqs queues to consume message asynchronously. I have started consuming the messages using amazon sqs JMS api's. So I have implemented MessageListener and doing my work once message arrive in onMessage method. Since amazon sqs is charged based on request made to the server I would like to restrict polling interval to 1 minute or may be more since I do not need message immediately.

I there anyway we can configure polling interval in JMS or I should use amazon sqs API to handle this on my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In that case you could choose synchronous receive call i.e. `consumer.receive(timeout)` instead of message listener. You can make the receive call only when you want.

I am also wondering a bit as the onMessage method should be invoked by SQS messaging provider only when there is a message in the queue. There should be no polling involved here.

**Update:**

SQS provides JMS a implementation. So the AsyncMessageListener should definitely do the job your are looking for. This [AsyncMessageListener](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/jmsclient.html#samples) sample should help you.

Comment: SQS is just a provider and does not make any call to the clients consuming the messages. Client are responsible to get the message. consumer.receive is one way. Even we can do long polling on SQS, but I am looking for a way to achieve this using JMS API.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my blog post I wrote while back on this subject: http://thedulinreport.com/2015/05/09/guaranteeing-delivery-of-messages-with-aws-sqs/

The blog post explains how to implement asynchronous listeners using nothing but AWS SDK as well as provides links to examples on github.

Comment: What is the producer and consumer are in two different microservices?

Comment: That post is outdated, but there is nothing stopping producer and consumer from being on two different microservices in that example.