# How to pace the consumption of a sqs queue using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, amazon-sqs, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to set up a integration flow to consume messages from a amazon sqs queue and its working fine so far. But i would like to pace the number of messages per minutes or seconds. e.g. 20 messages per minute.

Here is the definition of my sql listener bean

```
    @Bean
    public MessageProducer mySqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter() {
        SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(this.amazonSqs, queueName);
        adapter.setMessageDeletionPolicy(SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS);

        adapter.setVisibilityTimeout(TIMEOUT_VISIBILITY);
        adapter.setWaitTimeOut(TIMEOUT_MESSAGE_WAIT);
        adapter.setMaxNumberOfMessages(prefetch);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(processMessageChannel());
        return adapter;
    }
```

As you can see, I'm setting the maximum number of messages to fetch per poll, but how to set the delay between polls?

In a regular jms queue I could use a JMS.inboundAdapter using a custom poller but it seems that using SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter I cant set any poll timer value.

Maybe I could use a MessageProducer other than SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter but which one?

Is it possible to set a JMS.inboundAdapter using sqs?

Comment: It seens the solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667321/polling-interval-for-jms-messagelistener-with-sqs-provider?rq=1. In this case this question could be considered duplicated, but the point here is that I'm using spring-integration. I will try to adapt the solution present there if it works i will close this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Integration `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is a message-driver active component. It is based on the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` from the Springh Cloud AWS project which has long-running `while()` loop to call `AmazonSQS.receiveMessage()`. The logic in that loop isn't too complicated:

```
try {
    ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = getAmazonSqs().receiveMessage(this.queueAttributes.getReceiveMessageRequest());
    CountDownLatch messageBatchLatch = new CountDownLatch(receiveMessageResult.getMessages().size());
    for (Message message : receiveMessageResult.getMessages()) {
        if (isQueueRunning()) {
            MessageExecutor messageExecutor = new MessageExecutor(this.logicalQueueName, message, this.queueAttributes);
                 getTaskExecutor().execute(new SignalExecutingRunnable(messageBatchLatch, messageExecutor));
        } else {
           messageBatchLatch.countDown();
        }
    }
    try {
         messageBatchLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
```

As you see we create there `messageBatchLatch` and wait for it after the loop.
Each messages is processed by their own `SignalExecutingRunnable` which `countDown()`s in the end of `MessageExecutor`. So, what you would like to do maybe achieved with an artificial `Thread.sleep()` in the target service method to have some more interval in between SQS polls.

But I hear your request and we indeed have to add something like:

```
/**
 * The sleep interval in milliseconds used in the main loop between shards polling cycles.
 * Defaults to {@code 1000} minimum {@code 250}.
 * @param idleBetweenPolls the interval to sleep between shards polling cycles.
 */
public void setIdleBetweenPolls(int idleBetweenPolls) {
    this.idleBetweenPolls = Math.max(250, idleBetweenPolls);
}
```

I did this for the `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`, but here we have to request Spring Cloud AWS to do that for the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`.